# Solr query is returning partial matches for one field, and not a different field

Tags: java, solr

I have a search autocomplete on my site, and I'm using Solr to find matching documents. I am trying to get partial matches on page titles, so for example Java* would match Java, Javascript, etc. As of right now, the autocomplete is set up to give me partial matches on all of the text in the page, which gives some weird results, so I've decided to switch over to using the page title. However, when I try to switch the search term from `text` for the page text to `title`, the query suddenly does not pick up partial matches any more. Here is an example of my original query:

```
q=text:java^2+text:"java"
  &hl=true&hl.snippets=1&hl.fragsize=25&hl.fl=title&start=0&rows=3
```

Unfortunately, the guy who set this up for me does not work with me any more, so I have little idea what's going on 'under the hood'. I'm using Spring/J2EE for my backend, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the field is no string based field. You can lookup this if you take a look at your `schema.xml`. If you search with `Java*` inside a string field it will match only titles which start with `Java*`.

Another thing is that you need to make sure that you are aware that Wildcard Queries are case sensitive ([see this](http://osdir.com/ml/solr-user.lucene.apache.org/2009-02/msg00383.html)).

Comment: The weird thing is that the query that we were previously using does not use the wildcard at all, and it still picked up partial matches. Any reason why that would be?

Comment: That depends a bit. If you have a tokenizer configured it may tokenize words on certain criteria. There is e.g. a PatternTokenizer which splits something like `Java2Me` in `java` `2` `me` so if you search for Java texts with Java2Me will be returned also.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the field title was analyzed, look at schema.xml to see what type the field is and how its analyzed to create term. Easy way to do that would be to go to solr admin http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/analysis.jsp, choose the same name option, type in the field name (am guessing 'title') put some sample text and query to see what terms are created and matched.